# Plotting an elliptic curve in SageMath

Tags: sage, python

I have never used SageMath in my life and I am relying on the internet for a crash course on how to get what I want out of SageMath (to plot an elliptic curve over a finite field).

I'm using [this code](http://wstein.org/talks/20090623-elliptic_curves/sagedays16-stein-elliptic_curves.pdf), pasted below:

```
@interact
def f(label='37a', p=tuple(prime_range(1000))):
 try: E = EllipticCurve(label)
 except:
 print "invalid label %s"%label; return
 try:
show(graphics_array([plot(E,thickness=3),plot(E.change_ring(GF(p)))]),frame=True)
 except Exception, msg:
 print msg
```

There seems to be a bracket missing, but I don't have the experience to know where it should go. The error message I get is:

```
Error in lines 1-6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/sage/sage-6.10/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smc_sagews/sage_server.py", line 905, in execute
    exec compile(block+'\n', '', 'single') in namespace, locals
  File "<string>", line 4
    except:
          ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: Also asked at http://ask.sagemath.org/question/32866/elliptic-curve-finite-field/

Comment: "There seems to be a bracket missing" - why would something that describes itself as an "indentation error", have anything to do with brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you've given seems to indicate that the line after `except:` is not indented more than `except:` is indented. Python cares about indentation levels a lot.

You might try the following.

```
@interact
def f(label='37a', p=tuple(prime_range(1000))):
    try:
        E = EllipticCurve(label)
    except:
        print "invalid label %s"%label; return
    try:
        show(graphics_array([plot(E,thickness=3), plot(E.change_ring(GF(p)))]), frame=True)
    except Exception, msg:
        print msg
```

Aside: You should use four spaces before code to have them display as a codeblock. For more, see [How do I format My Code Blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Is it possible to change the curve being plotted in this code?

Comment: @Alice I'm guessing that the label refers to the Cremona labelling of an elliptic curve. So you should change the label heading to whatever curve you are interested in. For instance, you might try label='35a1' or something to pick up that elliptic curve. [I don't actually have sage open in front of me, but that seems like the way to go]

Comment: In the interact you could even make a list of all relevant labels and put that in the `label` option.